# Java custom Iterator (Generator), List<E> or E[]?

Tags: java, iterator

I am implementing a custom generator in Java, for spirals, and I am wondering which approach is better:

```
public class SpiralIterator<E> implements Iterator<List<E>> {
    private final int parameters;

    public SpiralIterator(int parameters) {
        this.parameters = parameters;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public List<E> next() {
        //...
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }
}
```

or

```
public class SpiralIterator<E> implements Iterator<E[]> {
    private final int parameters;

    public SpiralIterator(int parameters) {
        this.parameters = parameters;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public E[] next() {
        //...
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }
}
```

Let's say you create it with `SpiralIterator<Integer> spiralIterator = new SpiralIterator<>(2);`.

Then you get the new element via `List<E> next = spiralIterator.next();` and subsequently get the elements with `E e1 = next.get(0);` and `E e2 = next.get(1);` respectively. In the other case you retrieve it via `E[] next = spiralIterator.next();` and subsequently get via `E e1 = next[0];` and `E e2 = next[1];`.

Which of the two approaches is preferred?

Also would it be 'allowed' (in terms of conventions) to call it a `SpiralGenerator`?

Comment: What is more convenient for the calling code? An array or a list?

Comment: @assylias I personally would say the list due to dynamicity between spiral arms, and due to the fact that it can get an overridden iterator or methods.

Comment: It's usually a good idea not to mix arrays with generics. So I'd prefer the `List` version.

Answer (score 0):

Any specific reason for **IMPLEMENTING Iterator**?

Or there can be a better option;

```
Class Spiral{

   // Your instances 

   // Getters

   // Setters

   // Methods

}

 Main Method{

    List<Spiral> spiralList = new ArrayList<Spiral>();

    // Perform your operations.
}
```

Also, in case you have to go the route for **Implementing the List interface,** I would prefer List than the array.